# MultilayerPerceptronClassifier in Spark. Layers and strange errors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neural-network, apache-spark-mllib, perceptron

I'm continuing to experience some strange bugs while using different values for layers[] parameter of MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.

e.g. for the same data:

```
int[] layers = {100, 98, 2}
new MultilayerPerceptronClassifier().setLayers(layers).setLabelCol(targetColumn).fit(data);
```

I get:  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
With stack trace: 
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1890)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1916)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1930)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1134)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.LBFGS$.runLBFGS(LBFGS.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.LBFGS.optimize(LBFGS.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardTrainer.train(Layer.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.train(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:262)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.train(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:147)
```

Now, I'm switching to

```
int[] layers = {10,8,2}
```

everything seems working. Now the next attempt is:

```
int[] layers = {9,6,2}
```

And got output which look much more weird:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (vector) => double)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: A & B Dimension mismatch!
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.BreezeUtil$.dgemm(BreezeUtil.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.AffineLayerModel.eval(Layer.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.forward(Layer.scala:483)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.predict(Layer.scala:530)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predict(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:322)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predict(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel$$anonfun$1.apply(Predictor.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel$$anonfun$1.apply(Predictor.scala:186)
        ... 16 more
17/02/08 12:55:34 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 68.0 (TID 68, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (vector) => double)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: A & B Dimension mismatch!
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.BreezeUtil$.dgemm(BreezeUtil.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.AffineLayerModel.eval(Layer.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.forward(Layer.scala:483)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.predict(Layer.scala:530)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predict(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:322)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predict(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel$$anonfun$1.apply(Predictor.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel$$anonfun$1.apply(Predictor.scala:186)
        ... 16 more

17/02/08 12:55:34 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 68.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
17/02/08 12:55:34 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 68.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/02/08 12:55:34 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 68
17/02/08 12:55:34 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 68 (show at DataPipeline.java:213) failed in 0,910 s
17/02/08 12:55:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 67 failed: show at DataPipeline.java:213, took 0,914385 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 68.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 68.0 (TID 68, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (vector) => double)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: A & B Dimension mismatch!
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.BreezeUtil$.dgemm(BreezeUtil.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.AffineLayerModel.eval(Layer.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.forward(Layer.scala:483)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.predict(Layer.scala:530)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predict(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:322)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predict(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel$$anonfun$1.apply(Predictor.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel$$anonfun$1.apply(Predictor.scala:186)
        ... 16 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1890)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1916)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:347)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2193)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2546)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2199)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1934)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2576)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:1934)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:526)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:486)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:495)
        at org.sparkexample.DataPipeline.trainNeuralNetwork(DataPipeline.java:213)
        at org.sparkexample.DataPipeline.selectModel(DataPipeline.java:184)
        at org.sparkexample.DataPipeline.main(DataPipeline.java:131)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (vector) => double)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: A & B Dimension mismatch!
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.BreezeUtil$.dgemm(BreezeUtil.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.AffineLayerModel.eval(Layer.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.forward(Layer.scala:483)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.predict(Layer.scala:530)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predict(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:322)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predict(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel$$anonfun$1.apply(Predictor.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel$$anonfun$1.apply(Predictor.scala:186)
        ... 16 more
```

So what exactly should I pass to layers. From docs I'm seeing that basically that the last parameter is num of classes, and the rest are arbitrary array of different neurons.

The real amount of features that I have and pass as 1 feature-vector is 9

Comment: Others also facing this issue may want to also check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73446989/8523960, I had same issues and found out the error depends on the pipeline & associated algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Found out experimentally, that the requested amount of neurons for input is

numFeatures + 1

So my assumption is that +1 is because of predictionCol.

Strange, since [Prepare data for MultilayerPerceptronClassifier in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844591/prepare-data-for-multilayerperceptronclassifier-in-scala) recommends only numFeatures amount of neurons

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I'm hoping it will be useful to people who come across this question.

The size of the first layer has to be exactly equal to the number of features.

The number of neurons in the first layer is equal to the second number you see in your feature vector. In my case:

[0,254,[233,238,239,240,241,242,243,248,249,250,251,252,253],[1,1,-1198.8500584795331,1,628,136,-999,-999,0.008856682769726247,0.05357142857142857,0.016624040920716114,0.22457200402819738,0.21739130434782608]]

So the size of my first layer is 254.