# requirement failed: A & B Dimension mismatch! : Multilayer Perceptron Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, deep-learning, classification, multilabel-classification, multi-layer

I build a pipeline with the Multilayerperceptronclassifier but when I try to evaluate the results I obtain an error. Can anyone hel me to fix the problem?
I think there is no problem with the pipeline before the classifier since I used with several classifiers and it works. I Have 3 label to predict.

```
Error: An error occurred while calling o554.evaluate.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 127.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 127.0 (TID 123) (70c695f6a9e1 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function (ProbabilisticClassificationModel$$Lambda$4201/0x00000008417dd840: (struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: A & B Dimension mismatch!
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.BreezeUtil$.dgemm(BreezeUtil.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.AffineLayerModel.eval(Layer.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.forward(Layer.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.predictRaw(Layer.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predictRaw(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predictRaw(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassificationModel.$anonfun$transform$2(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:121)
    ... 19 more
```

```
train,test, validation = df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.2, 0.1], 1234)
mlp = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(labelCol = 'label',
                                            featuresCol = 'features',
                                            maxIter=100,
                                            layers=[11, 4, 5, 3],
                                            seed=1234)
stages.append(mlp)

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
model = pipeline.fit(train)
pred = model.transform(test)

accuracy = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy").evaluate(pred)
precision = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="weightedPrecision").evaluate(pred)
recall = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="weightedRecall").evaluate(pred)
f1 = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="f1").evaluate(pred)

print("Test Error = %g" % (1.0 - accuracy))
print("Accuracy = %g" % (accuracy))
print("Precision = %g" % (precision))
print("Recall = %g" % (recall))
print("F1 = %g" % (f1))
accuracy = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy").evaluate(pred)
precision = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="weightedPrecision").evaluate(pred)
recall = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="weightedRecall").evaluate(pred)
f1 = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="f1").evaluate(pred)

print("Test Error = %g" % (1.0 - accuracy))
print("Accuracy = %g" % (accuracy))
print("Precision = %g" % (precision))
print("Recall = %g" % (recall))
print("F1 = %g" % (f1))
```

Comment: what's the number of your `features` ? Should be (equal to number of inputs,  11 in your case), have you checked that too?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies most likely on your pipeline. It will be hard to help without seeing the various algorithms you used prior to your `mlp`. However, here is a general solution:

E.g: if you have `11 features` columns & perform the following algorithms:
`agorithm1 --> agorithm2 --> vectorassember -->  MultilayerPerceptronClassifier`

At `vectorassember`, you could be having `1000s of features`, e.g. `(20000,[155,268,27...])`, in which case your input layer would have `20000` nodes, not just the `11 columns` of your initial features columns.
So,
`layers = [11, 4, 5, 3]` will throw the error:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: A & B Dimension mismatch!`

And so,
`layers = [20000, 4, 5, 3]` will be correct.